# Reactjs Map function could not display search records

Tags: reactjs

**Reactjs**  Map function could not display search records

Believe me I have search previous post but most solution could not address my issue.

The code below successfully display searched records from database in a **json format** as user types data within the search text box as can be
seen in the screenshot below.

[image]
Here is my issue. The search data is showed in a json format as can be seen in the screenshot above.
now I want to display search records with **map() method/function** as per this code

```
<ul>
            {this.state.data.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.lastName} - {obj.firstName} -- {obj.id}



              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

but it shows error below

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at NameForm.render .**

It seems to me that Map() is trying to read data as page loads but gets nothing. can someone help me with any possible solution.

**here is the code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="rootsearch"></label>

    <script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.state = {value: ''};
this.state = {email: ''};
//this.state= {data: []}

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

$(".search").keyup(function() 
{
var email = this.state.email;
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/apidb_react/search_react3.php",

data: {

'email': this.state.email
},
cache: false,

       //dataType: 'json',
       //ContentType: 'application/json',
       success: function(data) {
         this.setState({data: data});
       }.bind(this),
       error: function(jqXHR) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
       }.bind(this)
    })
}.bind(this))// end search

  }



render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <input placeholder="Search by Names" id="email" name="email" type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>


/*
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.lastName} - {obj.firstName} -- {obj.id}



              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
*/



        {
         this.state.data

        }
      </span>
   );    
}



}
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('rootsearch')
);


 </script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic under _Questions seeking debugging help_.

Comment: this.state.data is undefined. Your code shows the line is commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the constructor

```
this.state = { data : [], value: “”, email: “”}
```

Comment: Thanks Franco. Implemented your solution inline with filter functions which passed within the Map Array method and got it working as a second alternative. Thanks

Comment: Your solution really help me as I forget that Map  function only accepts arrays data not objects

Answer (score 0):

My best bet so far was to implement **filter function** and pass it within the Map Array method. I just ensured that the returned data is Array following **Coronel Franco** solution here.

```
// Coronel Franco Solutions
    this.state = { data : [], value: “”, email: “”}

// create filterRecord function
filterRecords(){
//parameter Lastname, firstname to be filter goes here
}
```

in the render method I implement the codes below

```
{
     this.state.data.filter(this.filterRecords).map((obj, i) => 
          (
            <li key={i}>
              {obj.lastName} - {obj.firstName}  - {obj.id} 

             </li>
          )
      )
}
```

Thanks